# Edit attribute value in an HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I've got a string. The string contains html. I'm checking the string for 'name', if it doesn't have one I'm using sneaking one in there if it does I need to change what it is.

```
var myString = '<input id="accountUser_c967817c993e62b1de50e4f0401a03ae" type="hidden" value="c967817c993e62b1de50e4f0401a03ae" name="addRow[]"><div class="colors goldbluegreenorange"></div>';
if (myString.indexOf('name') == -1) {
    myString = myString.substr(0,myString.indexOf('>')) + ' name="addRow[]"' + myString.substr(myString.indexOf('>'));
} else {
    //get what's inside name's quotes and change it to removeRow[]. 
}
```

I've got jquery going on too, if that makes more sense than straight javascript.

Comment: Not a great idea to name your variable `string`. Just saying.

Comment: oh, I see that now. it was just for example purposes. I didn't do it IRL.

Comment: OK. Sorry for the noise. Keep up the good work.

Comment: NP. Thanks for keeping me straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, why not create a jQuery element out of that string, so that we can use jQuery's beautiful API for this? It'll make it far less error-prone than raw string manipulation.

Here's some sample code:

```
var $element = $('<input id="accountUser_c967817c993e62b1de50e4f0401a03ae" type="hidden" value="c967817c993e62b1de50e4f0401a03ae" name="addRow[]"><div class="colors goldbluegreenorange"></div>');

$element.filter('input').prop('name', function(i, v) {
    return v ? 'removeRow[]' : 'addRow[]';
});
```

**Note:** the `v` in that function is the current value of the `name` attribute, which jQuery automatically passes in to the callback function. The return value is what the value of the attribute should be updated to.

---

**Update**: If you then want to convert it all back into a string, use this:

```
var theHTMLstring = $element.wrapAll('<div>').parent().html();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kBF3c/

Comment: I think I understand what's going on here. How do I stick that back into my first variable?

Comment: @davimusprime - Not sure what you're asking. Did you see me last update? What are you trying to accomplish? What are you gonna do with that string?

Comment: the string is actually coming from part of an array for managing some fancy table stuff, datatables.net.

Also, I missed your update the first time :D

Comment: $element.wrap('<div>').parent().html(); is only returning the input (and not the div). That my bad?

Comment: @davimusprime - Nope. My bad. It should be `wrapAll` instead of just `wrap`. I updated my answer and added a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use jQuery's inbuilt functionality.

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/zfmCP/)**

```
// specify string representing input element
var str = '<input id="accountUser_c967817c993e62b1de50e4f0401a03ae" type="hidden" value="c967817c993e62b1de50e4f0401a03ae" name="addRow[]"><div class="colors goldbluegreenorange"></div>';

var els = $(str);
// create element
var el = $(els).filter("input");

if( $(el).prop("name") ) {
    $(el).prop( "name", "removeRow[]" );
} else {
    $(el).prop("name", "anynameyouwant");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
}
```

I am guessing you need to add the the above elements to the DOM which you can do like so

```
$("#parentId").append( els );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the string to a jQuery object and reading the parameter from that:

```
var myString = '<input id="accountUser_c967817c993e62b1de50e4f0401a03ae" type="hidden" value="c967817c993e62b1de50e4f0401a03ae" name="addRow[]"><div class="colors goldbluegreenorange"></div>';
var $input = $(myString).filter('input');
$input.attr('name') = ($input.attr('name') == "") ? 'addRow[]' : 'removeRow[]';
```

Comment: Don't. You really shouldn't be dealing with HTML as a string. If you need to amend/append it use jQuery.

Comment: I have to use it as a string. It's actually a part of an array for datatables.net. I'm moving a row from one table to another but have to modify the input for the behind the scenes form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery anyways, why don't you just *parse* the string and treat the tags as HTML?

```
var html = $.parseXML(string);
$.each(html.find('*'),function()
{
    if ($(this).attr('name'))
    {
        $(this).attr('name', 'addRow[]');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).attr('name','removeRow[]');
    }
});
```

And take things from there?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
var str = '<input id="accountUser_c967817c993e62b1de50e4f0401a03ae" type="hidden" value="c967817c993e62b1de50e4f0401a03ae" name="addRow[]"><div class="colors goldbluegreenorange"></div>';
$(str).prop('name', (!$(str).prop('name') ? "addRow[]" : "removeRow[]"));
str=$('<div/>').html(obj).html(); // str contains new value
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J7x7J/1/).